# How to write unit test with Jest, Fastdom and Preact

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, frontend, preact

I am working on a project that uses fastdom, typescript and preact, and @testing-library/preact. But when I try to write a test, it complains that fastdom is undefined.

My question is how does the fastdom and the preact testing library work? I suppose it runs only that component I render, but it doesn't seem to the case.

here is my code

```
// SearchResult.test.tsx
import SearchResult from '##/components/SearchResult';

describe('Search Result', () => {
  it('should start with a blank screen', () => {
    render(<SearchResult isLoading={false} />);
    expect(screen.children.length).toEqual(0);
  });
});
```

Error Message: [image]

Comment: Have you imported `fastdom` somewhere? It's not going to attach itself to the window if you haven't.

Comment: it is imported through index.html with the script tag.

Comment: Jest isn't a web app. It will not load a HTML file. You need to import it in your test suite.